# Encrypt already saved files on a computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

```
from string import maketrans

intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

print "Do you want to translate a random term, or a file?(Please enter file name in the code)"
RandOrFile = raw_input ("Type 1 to enter a custom term, or 2 to translate a whole file")
if RandOrFile == "1":
    inputA = raw_input ("Enter a phrase to translate")
    str = inputA
    print str.translate(trantab);
elif RandOrFile == "2":
```

(Code for my program)
I am attempting to create a program which encrypts a file, and turns the letters into other letters, like an Enigma Machine (But much more simple). I have made it so that you can directly translate user entered phrases, as the top chunk of the code shows, but I cant work out how to translate already made files on the users computer.

The code is meant to go under the "elif RandOrFile == "2"" line, but I cant work out how to a) fetch the data from a specified file on a computer, and b) work out how to translate that file in the program.

I have researched, but I cant find any ways to do so. My python skills are very beginner, so if you could possibly quote relevant sources to help on this, that would also be helpful, although I have tried, i'm not really sure where to begin while looking through tutorial websites.

Comment: The first thing you should probably do is place your translation code into a separate function.  This will make it easier to reuse it.  Then, do some research on how to work with files.  I suggest that you start with the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).